# How to reduce Cython compiled code's interaction with Python

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to reduce a particularly computational heavy piece of Python code through compiling as C with Cython.  Surprisingly I have virtually no success in speeding it up.  With the original Python module the code runs in about 45sec and with the Cython compiled module it runs in about 45secs.

Compiling with `annotate=True`, I am left with a sea of yellow(ish) lines suggesting there is still a huge amount of Python interaction.

I have responded to this by switching off both `boundscheck (False)` and `cdivision (True)`.  This had no effect.  The following snippet of code is an extract from this module and it insists on interacting with Python.  Why is this?  Nothing here need to interact with any pre-existing Python module, it is all very simple arithmatic?

```
cpdef float __distance_between(point1, point2)  except? -2:
    return ((point1[0] - point2[0]) ** 2 + (point1[1] - point2[1]) ** 2) ** (1/2)
```

`point1` and `point2` are Python lists each containing 2 `double`s eg: `[611811.997, -871083.372]` The resulting `C`-code that is generated by Cython for the `return` line in the snippet is as follows:

```
+05: cpdef float __distance_between(point1, point2)  except? -2:
+06:     return ((point1[0] - point2[0]) ** 2 + (point1[1] - point2[1]) ** 2)**(1/2)
  __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_GetItemInt(__pyx_v_point1, 0, long, 1, __Pyx_PyInt_From_long, 0, 0, 0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_GetItemInt(__pyx_v_point2, 0, long, 1, __Pyx_PyInt_From_long, 0, 0, 0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
  __pyx_t_3 = PyNumber_Subtract(__pyx_t_1, __pyx_t_2); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_3);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
  __pyx_t_2 = PyNumber_Power(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_int_2, Py_None); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_3 = 0;
  __pyx_t_3 = __Pyx_GetItemInt(__pyx_v_point1, 1, long, 1, __Pyx_PyInt_From_long, 0, 0, 0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_3);
  __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_GetItemInt(__pyx_v_point2, 1, long, 1, __Pyx_PyInt_From_long, 0, 0, 0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_t_4 = PyNumber_Subtract(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_t_1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_4);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_3 = 0;
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
  __pyx_t_1 = PyNumber_Power(__pyx_t_4, __pyx_int_2, Py_None); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_4); __pyx_t_4 = 0;
  __pyx_t_4 = PyNumber_Add(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_4);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
  __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_long((1 / 2)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_t_2 = PyNumber_Power(__pyx_t_4, __pyx_t_1, Py_None); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_4); __pyx_t_4 = 0;
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
  __pyx_t_5 = __pyx_PyFloat_AsFloat(__pyx_t_2); if (unlikely((__pyx_t_5 == (float)-1) && PyErr_Occurred())) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
  __pyx_r = __pyx_t_5;
  goto __pyx_L0;
```

How can I better optimise the code or the compilation to make this snippet independent of Python?

There are many other lines in this module that are all rendered pretty yellow, but starting with this question may provide me with a better understanding of how to tackle the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't `cdef`ed any of your variables; *you* know they're `float`, Cython doesn't. Tell it.

```
cpdef float __distance_between((double, double)point1, (double, double)point2)  except? -2:
    return ((point1[0] - point2[0]) ** 2 + (point1[1] - point2[1]) ** 2) ** (1/2)
```

Comment: Side-note: Make sure you're compiling it with `-3` to opt in to Python 3 syntax, or `1/2` will be interpreted as `0`; alternatively, just change it to a literal `0.5` (or `1. / 2.` or the like) and it will work regardless of which syntax (Py2 vs. Py3) you're using.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue.  And thanks for the pointer on `1/2`.

Comment: However, if the points as genuinely python lists of floats, there isn't a Cython data type that expresses this efficiently. You've just moved the work to some conversions in the function call.

Comment: @DavidW: It would still improve performance meaningfully. Sure, you need to make the conversions up front, but it turns a bunch of `PyNumber` generic API calls into raw C operations. Four unpackings and one repacking isn't great, but in between it's all raw C `double` operations, much better than six generic `PyNumber` operations (each of which has to unpack two operands, perform math, and repack the result to Python `float`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes fair point - I think you're right that it will help and I think that's as far as it's possible to go with optimization without knowing a bit more exactly how OP is using the function.